# Creating self referencing relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I want to be able to make relationships between a captain and his referrals. They both belong to the same table. I have this in my model

```
public function captain() {
    $this->belongsTo('User', 'referral_id') ;
} 

 public function captain() {
    $this->hasMany('User', 'referral_id') ;
 }
```

My users table has the following columns 
id name referral_id referred_by

```
1 xyz         1223          null
2 Abc         4525          1223
```

How do I create the relationship better? And I want to know if I can and how I can use this to get the referral of a referral of the captain

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't create a table referral?

Comment: @Wistar i have seen cases where people make self referencing relationships and i want to know if it's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create a second table for your referrals - then you create a relationship between your captain ID in table 1 over in table 2 where all the referers can be stored. If you setup the relationship, you then simply call something like

```
$captains = App\Captain::all();

foreach ($captains as $captain) {
    echo $captain->referrals->name;
}
```

ref
using simple eager loading... or ->with using other methods (or join etc)